# How to handle up key from console application

Tags: python

I'm using Python 2.6 and I want to know how I can use the up key from the console.
I don't want to use Tkinter or another GUI library at this moment.

Below is my code.

```
history=[]    
while(1): 
    try:
        cmd = self.get_cmd()
        history.append(cmd)   # append user command
        # if i press UP key, just display history. 
        # i'll you for statement to disaply history.
        print "%s" %history
```

Comment: who edited this? :| this is not valid python code :-/

Comment: Does it need to be cross-platform? If not, what platform?

Answer (score 2):

For your goals, you can look to [readline](http://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html) module, it is designed for things like history handling and so on. It's standard python library, so it can be what you need. And with other module, [rlcompleter](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/rlcompleter.html) you can even handle autocompletion.